# How to create a line to show threshold in bar graph

Tags: javascript, cordova, flot

I am using flot to create bar charts like

[image: Bar Graph]

I need to specify a threshold like a line at 750(y axis) for example, to show the limit...
there is one jquery.flot.threshold.js file in flot package, but i dont know how to use it on bar charts.How to do it ?

Comment: Which version of flot are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems there was [some issues](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=522) with using the threshold plugin with the current flot release version.  If you just want to mark a threshold, it might be easier to use the grid markings option:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ], {
    series: {
        stack: true,      
        bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.6 }
    },
    grid: {
           markings: [ { xaxis: { from: 0, to: 12 }, yaxis: { from: 0, to: 20 }, color: "#6D7B8D" }]
        }
});
```

Produces (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/F2z97/)):

[image]

Comment: According to the issue you linked to, this should be working in 0.7.

Comment: From the change logs it looks like 0.7 was released Mar 21, 2011 and this was fixed Apr 4, 2011.