# Add a "Target Line" to a Coldfusion 8 CFChart Bar Graph

Tags: graph, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfchart

I have a Coldfusion CfChart Bar Graph, that has X-Axis = Questions, and Y-Axis = Scores (0-100), but what I want to do is add a a Target Score Line on the graph, that goes across the X-Axis at the Y-Axis 85 Mark. Is this possible at all?

I noticed something similar for Javascript on here: [How to create a line to show threshold in bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092263/how-to-create-a-line-to-show-threshold-in-bar-graph)

I was just wondering if it was possible to do something similar in Coldfusion.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can generate background ranges by using a custom style. See [CFCHART-Tip--Background-Ranges](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2008/10/23/Cool-CFCHART-Tip--Background-Ranges)

ie Using the `<limits>` element

```
<frameChart is3d="false">
    <yAxis>
      <limits index="0" min="0" max="85" color="#ff8000"/>
    </yAxis>
</frameChart>
```