# Coldfusion 10 cfcharts:Target line on a bar chart

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfchart

I basically have a bar chart showing the score of individuals and I want to add a few line in the chart representing the different levels (i.e. the 65% is pass, 75% is fair, etc) something like this [Add a “Target Line” to a Coldfusion 8 CFChart Bar Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813386/add-a-target-line-to-a-coldfusion-8-cfchart-bar-graph) only in coldfusion 10 which supports html format.
Thanks guys,

Comment: You should post that as an answer so it is easier to find. (Answering your own question is allowed). Then delete the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use markers. This is how you do it:

```
"scale-y":{"zooming":true,"thousands-separator":",","markers":
    [{"type":"line","range":[1500000],"alpha":"1","line-color":"#ff0000",
    "line-style":"solid","label":{"text":"Minimum","color":"#f00"}}]},
```

Check the example http://www.cfuser.com/library/demos/index.cfm?do=charting&get=barline

Answer (score 0):

Its the use of markers in scale-y using type line and range [ - wherever number you want -]